# How to save images from one website (domain) to another website (domain) in asp mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a project for client in asp.net MVC 5. There are two domains (projects), one project is for Admin and one project is for website (customer side). There is a folder in admin project where admin can save user documents. Now my client wants to give an option in the customer project for file uploading by user in the same folder in admin project. Now how can I save files(images) from one project ( customer side)  to admin project (admin side) in asp mvc 5? I am using asp.net mvc 5. Both projects are hosted on two different domains.

Comment: Could you please tell me are these two server are hosted on the same server or hosted on the different server, but in the same domain?

Comment: These two projects admin and website are hosted on two different hosting companies.

Comment: As far as I know, if the host server is not inside same domain, you should use ftp services or use web api to allow remote connection.